# How to install texlive2011?

Tags: 11.10, latex

I just moved from Windows to Ubuntu. Software Center in Ubuntu does have texlive2009 package. There is no straightforward installation process from TUG, or from Google search result. I found some installation of Texlive2010 but it does not work.

Here are the step:

- download an texlive2011.iso, 2.3GB and save in local drive
- mount to a virtual drive
- install perl tk (ok)
- "sudo ./install-tl" does not work, "perl ./install-tl" shows pre-installation setting but it does not have the write access to /usr/local/textlive/2011/
- Finally, I'm stuck

Please guide me with a step by step tutorial or suggest any other solution beside typing in the black screen without knowing what is going on behind the Terminal.

Comment: have you tried to change permissions to the /usr/local/texlive/2011/ dir?

Comment: or even `sudo perl ./install-tl` ?

Also see this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521

Comment: Also assume you have read this: http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html ?

Answer (score 2):

**Installing TeXLive 2011 on Ubuntu 11.10**

You will need a script from [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/eZSpENE3...e_texlive.html)

1. Open terminal, go to the directory where you downloaded the script and make it executable with
   Code:

   chmod +x install_update_texlive.sh
2. Execute the script with
   Code:

   ./install_update_texlive.sh

   *A window will pop up. The choices there are self explanatory.*

   ~3 GB of data will be downloaded
3. After a short while a window appear with different settings. Again, self explanatory. Choose your languages, packages. I chose to download all of it so there are no hiccups later. Click next.
4. All you have to do now is wait. For the impatient there is a progress bar.
   Attached Files
   File Type: [sh  install_update_texlive.sh](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=209185&d=1324022596)

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896049)

Answer (score 1):

Answered as the previous answers rely on a custom script or using an outdated repository. These instructions are now for TeX Live 2013 as this is currently the latest version.

Heavily borrowed from an answer by [Silex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17484/silex): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/34985 . Key points included here and updated for TeX Live 2013.

Tested on Linux Mint 13 with TeX Live 2013 but should work for most Debian based distributions.

### Installation

Be aware that the full installation requires 3GB of free space. Alternatively, you can opt for a minimal installation and install packages later as you need them.

Download the official installer, untar and navigate to the new folder

```
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl-*
```

To install run the following (be patient, this can take a while to start up)

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

The installer will provide you with some options, read through and choose any as necessary, although the defaults should be fine. Type `i` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to start installing, which can take a while.

If the installation is interrupted or fails, delete the installed files before trying again

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2013
```

### Create symbolic links

To make your operating system play nicely with TeX Live, create a symbolic link to the install location

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/* /opt/texbin
```

Add TeX Live to your `$PATH`. This can be done by editing `/etc/environment`

```
gksudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Which should look like

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

Add `/opt/texbin` to the front of the path

```
PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

Save, logout and login to make the changes work.

To test that this worked, open the terminal and run

```
which tex
```

This should show

```
/opt/texbin/tex
```

### equivs package

To let Ubuntu know that you've installed TeX Live, create some fake packages using `equivs`

```
sudo apt-get install equivs --no-install-recommends
mkdir /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs
equivs-control texlive-local
```

Edit `texlive-local`

```
gedit texlive-local
```

then replace the contents with the following

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: texlive-local
Version: 2013
Maintainer: you <you@yourdomain.example.org>
Provides: biblatex, biblatex-dw, cm-super, cm-super-minimal, context, dvipng,
 feynmf, fragmaster, lacheck, latex-beamer, latex-cjk-all, latex-cjk-chinese,
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp,
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp,
 latex-cjk-common, latex-cjk-japanese, latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab,
 latex-cjk-korean, latex-cjk-thai, latex-cjk-xcjk, latexmk, latex-sanskrit,
 latex-xcolor, lcdf-typetools, lmodern, luatex, musixlyr, musixtex, pgf,
 preview-latex-style, prosper, ps2eps, psutils, purifyeps, t1utils, tex4ht,
 tex4ht-common, tex-gyre, texlive, texlive-base, 
 texlive-bibtex-extra, texlive-binaries, texlive-common,
 texlive-doc-base, texlive-doc-bg, texlive-doc-cs+sk, texlive-doc-de,
 texlive-doc-el, texlive-doc-en, texlive-doc-es, texlive-doc-fi,
 texlive-doc-fr, texlive-doc-it, texlive-doc-ja, texlive-doc-ko,
 texlive-doc-mn, texlive-doc-nl, texlive-doc-pl, texlive-doc-pt,
 texlive-doc-ru, texlive-doc-si, texlive-doc-th, texlive-doc-tr,
 texlive-doc-uk, texlive-doc-vi, texlive-doc-zh, texlive-extra-utils,
 texlive-fonts-extra, texlive-fonts-extra-doc, texlive-fonts-recommended,
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc, texlive-font-utils, texlive-formats-extra,
 texlive-games, texlive-generic-extra, texlive-generic-recommended,
 texlive-humanities, texlive-humanities-doc, texlive-lang-african,
 texlive-lang-all, texlive-lang-arab, texlive-lang-arabic,
 texlive-lang-armenian, texlive-lang-croatian, texlive-lang-cyrillic,
 texlive-lang-czechslovak, texlive-lang-danish, texlive-lang-dutch,
 texlive-lang-finnish, texlive-lang-french, texlive-lang-german,
 texlive-lang-greek, texlive-lang-hebrew, texlive-lang-hungarian,
 texlive-lang-indic, texlive-lang-italian, texlive-lang-latin,
 texlive-lang-latvian, texlive-lang-lithuanian, texlive-lang-manju,
 texlive-lang-mongolian, texlive-lang-norwegian, texlive-lang-other,
 texlive-lang-polish, texlive-lang-portuguese, texlive-lang-spanish,
 texlive-lang-swedish, texlive-lang-tibetan, texlive-lang-ukenglish,
 texlive-lang-vietnamese, texlive-latex3, texlive-latex-base,
 texlive-latex-base-doc, texlive-latex-extra, texlive-latex-extra-doc,
 texlive-latex-recommended, texlive-latex-recommended-doc, texlive-luatex,
 texlive-math-extra, texlive-metapost, texlive-metapost-doc, texlive-music,
 texlive-omega, texlive-pictures, texlive-pictures-doc, texlive-plain-extra,
 texlive-pstricks, texlive-pstricks-doc, texlive-publishers,
 texlive-publishers-doc, texlive-science, texlive-science-doc, texlive-xetex,
 texpower, texpower-manual, thailatex, tipa, ttf-freefont, ttf-gfs-artemisia,
 ttf-gfs-baskerville, ttf-gfs-bodoni-classic, ttf-gfs-didot,
 ttf-gfs-didot-classic, ttf-gfs-gazis, ttf-gfs-neohellenic, ttf-gfs-olga,
 ttf-gfs-porson, ttf-gfs-solomos, ttf-gfs-theokritos, ttf-sil-gentium, xindy,
 xindy-rules
Architecture: all
Description: My local installation of TeX Live 2013.
 A full "vanilla" TeX Live 2013
 http://tug.org/texlive/debian#vanilla
```

Source: http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-control-ex.txt

Build the package and install it

```
equivs-build texlive-local
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2012-1_all.deb
```

After this installing `texworks` through the package maintainer won't install TeX Live again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install Texlive from the Ubuntu repositories? However, the standard Ubuntu software Center does not list everything. So just install "synaptic" over the Software Center.

After that open Synaptic and search for "texlive-full" which is a metapaket and will pull the complete texlive. After that just install texmaker, kile, etc and you are good to go.

Comment: TeX Live in the repos is TeX Live 2009 which is outdated (current is TeX Live 2011). Many people therefore install TeX Live directly from upstream.